# Avoid closing Jquery's FancyBox

Tags: jquery-plugins, fancybox

I am using fanxybox 1.2.6 but it's getting closed despite of mentionig *onContentClick:false*

Here is the code:

**$("#"+vari).fancybox({'hideOnContentClick':false }).trigger('click');**

Kindly help me out

p.s: The window is loading content from other URL(via Iframe)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the single quotes either side of the option name. Also, I've had issues in the past with the overlay fighting with the content, so if removing the quotes doesn't work, you might want to try adding hideOnOverlayClick:false.

```
$("#"+vari).fancybox({ 
    hideOnContentClick:false,
    hideOnOverlayClick:false
 }).trigger('click');
```